# Pass entire where condition as argument in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to pass entire where condition as parameter in Postgrel.

Is it possible? I have created procedure like,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pro_select_all_item_query_builder_data(IN cond character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name character varying) AS
$BODY$ 
BEGIN            
  FOR id, name IN

    SELECT product.id, product.name FROM product WHERE cond
.............
```

and call it like,

```
SELECT * 
FROM pro_select_all_item_query_builder_data('product.status_id = 1')
```

It showing ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character varying

Can you please support me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `cond` has a valid condition, otherwise it will throw syntax error.

```
FOR id, name IN
    EXECUTE ('SELECT product.id, product.name FROM product WHERE ' || cond)
LOOP
....
END LOOP;
```